# Как найти открытые тэги и закрыть их через JS или PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка

Есть например вот такой код:

```
<div>
текст рыба
<code>var a = 1;
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<pre>
<code>$b = 2;</code>
</div>
```

Любой из тэгов `code` или `pre` могут быть не закрытыми.
Из за этого возникает ошибки вывода.
Есть способы закрыть их программно в `PHP` или `JavaScript`?

Результат должен быть таким:

```
<div>
текст рыба
<code>var a = 1;</code>
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<pre>
<code>$b = 2;</code>
</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/ru/tidy.repairstring.php):

```
<?php

$html = '
<div>
текст рыба
<code>var a = 1;
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<pre>
<code>$b = 2;</code>
</div>
'
;

// Прочие настройки: @see http://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/quickref_5.0.0.html

$config = [
  'output-xhtml'    => true,
  'indent'          => true,
  'show-body-only'  => true,
  'force-output'    => true,
  'wrap'            => false
];


$tidy = new tidy();
echo $tidy->repairString($html, $config, 'utf8');
```

Результат:

```
<div>
  текст рыба <code>var a = 1;</code>
  <h1>
    <code>Заголовок</code>
  </h1>
  <pre>
<code><code>$b = 2;</code>
</code>
</pre>
</div>
```

Не совсем то, что ожидаете, но у вас синтетический пример.